# how to customize bootstrap columns padding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a customized bootstrap file which has the padding left and right set at 8px instead of the default 15px. The padding relates to the following in bootstrap.css file:

```
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

But I do not know which parameter I should change in the Bootstrap customization page.

Comment: Note that you can also override these settings in a custom `.css` file if you copy that css statement, change these values and include it *after* `bootstrap.css` (This is a quick fix, customizing and recompiling the source-code to fit your needs is great, but not as quick)

Comment: @Tim, although true. I was answering @ajax20's question. `I do not know which parameter I should change in the Bootstrap customization page.`

Comment: I know, and I didn't mean that as an alternative to your answer, it was just a general comment about the alternatives. You have the correct way of doing it. If that comment was aimed specifically at you, I would have said @ChrisYongchu. Also, since you answered this question from your comment, you can actually remove the comment and leave the answer.

Comment: True. I've removed my comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to make a customized bootstrap file which has the padding left and right set at 8px instead of the default 15px.

Notice that the default *Gutter width* is set to `30px (15px on each side of the column)`.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

If you want it changed to 8px instead of the 15px, change the `@grid-gutter-width` (http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system) value from 30px to 16px.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Chris for explaining it to me.

Answer (score 1):

For the case where you want to apply custom padding on EVERY row, replace `.my-custom-area` in solution below from to `body`.

For anyone who want to customize padding only on certain area of the page,

so you can still use the default bootstrap file and not stuck with only one setting of padding size, you can do the following:

1. Specify the area where to override the default padding. Here I use `.my-custom-area`.
2. For example we column padding to be 8px each on left and right side. Modify the margin of row in area #1 to negative value. `.my-custom-area .row { margin-left: -8px; margin-right: -8px;}`.

*Here we override the default settings for row, from bootstrap docs we know the row has default margin of negative value (-15px).

3. Modify the padding of col in area #1 `.my-custom-area .row > .col { padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 8px; }`

```css
.my-custom-area .row {
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-right: -8px;
}
.my-custom-area .row > .col {
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="default">
  <div class="container">
    <h5>
      Default (col padding: 15px on each side)</h5>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-md-4">
        <div class="card">This is 1st column</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-md-4">
        <div class="card">This is 2nd column</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-md-4">
        <div class="card">This is 3rd column</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="my-custom-area">
  <div class="container">
  <h5>Custom (col padding: 8px  on each side)</h5>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-md-4">
        <div class="card">This is 1st column</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-md-4">
        <div class="card">This is 2nd column</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-md-4">
        <div class="card">This is 3rd column</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```